# Loop over list items, except for the last two items (python)

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to for loop over a list of 14 items except for the last two items.
Does anybody know if there is a function or command in python which accomplishes this?

Comment: Same logic as duplicate link, just change the `1` to `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lists support slicing like this:

```
for i in your_list[:-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
random_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for element in random_list[:-2]:
     print(element)
```

[Out] :

```
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

optionally

```
items = [] # your 14 item long list here
for i in range(len(items)-2):
    print(items[i])
```